# Choose UIImage via Uniform Type Identifiers

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uti

In my iOS app I have to list documents in a `UITableView` and I want to associate them an `UIImage`. To choose image I have to follow this scheme

- IMAGE1 - file with extension **.doc**, **.docx**, **.ott**, **.odt**, **.dot**
- IMAGE2 - file with extension **.pdf**
- IMAGE3 - file with extension **.xls**, **xlsx**, **.ods**
- etc.

How can I choose the right `UIImage` by using **Uniform Type Identifiers** in `MobileCoreServices` iOS framework?

I write the following swift function:

```
public static func image(for pathExtension: String) -> UIImage {
        guard let rawUtis = UTTypeCreateAllIdentifiersForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, pathExtension as CFString, nil)?.takeRetainedValue() as? [String] else {
            return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "UNKNOWN")
        }
        for rawUti in rawUtis {
            if UTTypeConformsTo(rawUti as CFString, kUTTypePDF) {
                return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMAGE2")
            }
            if UTTypeConformsTo(rawUti as CFString, "com.microsoft.word.doc") || UTTypeConformsTo(rawUti as CFString, "org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document") || UTTypeConformsTo(rawUti as CFString, "org.oasis-open.opendocument.text-template") || UTTypeConformsTo(rawUti as CFString, "org.oasis-open.opendocument.text") || UTTypeConformsTo(rawUti as CFString, "com.microsoft.word.dot") {
                return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMAGE1")
            }
            // etc.
        }
    }
```

I'm using [FileKit](https://github.com/nvzqz/FileKit) to manage my documents' paths. My `cellForRowAt` looks like

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "documentCell", for: indexPath) as! DocumentViewCell

    let documentPath = ... // document's path from indexPath
    cell.nameLabel.text = documentPath.fileName
    cell.iconImageView?.image = UTI.image(for: documentPath.pathExtension)
    // ...
    return cell
}
```

I find `image` function very ugly. Is there a smarter way to achieve my goal?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need a UTI? You have the file extension. Just write a `switch` for the different possible extensions.

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been closed as duplicate... I doesn't think the linked post answers my question.

Comment: You just need to get the typeIdentifier from your file url. Where are you getting your pathExtension from? just switch the typeIdentifier from the url.

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus. Could you be more specific? How do I find right image from typeIdentifier?

Comment: Can you edit your question and show how you are calling this method?

Comment: @LeoDabus I edited my question. Thank you for your help.